# harmonic functions and ito formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to prove the mean-value property for harmonic functions in $R^k$ by ito calculus.

given $G$ bounded domain and $u$ harmonic function on $G$ then

$u(a)=\int_{\partial B_r} u(y)ds(y)$

$B_r$ is a ball in radius $r$ around a.

so far I took the stopping time $\tau:=\inf_{t\geq0} (t:B_t \notin G ) $ (_hitting time of brownian motion)

and used $\tau_b$ as hitting time of BM in a ball of radius r around a.

I used ito formula (with $B$ brownian motion) to get that

$u(B_{t \wedge \tau_b})=u(B_0)+\sum_{i=1}^{k}\int_{0}^{t \wedge \tau_b} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(B_s)dB_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t \wedge \tau_b}\Delta u ds
$

I know the last term is zero since $u$ harmonic but how can I continue from here I don't see the relation with integral over the ball surface

thank you

Comment: You actually want to stop the process when it hits $\partial B_r$, not when it hits $\partial G$. Call that stopping time $\tau$; then try to prove that $B_\tau$ is uniformly distributed on the sphere, so that $E[u(B_\tau)]$ is the integral at the top of your question. One way to see this is to note that if $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion then $Q B_t$ is also a Brownian motion.

Comment: This approach with Ito's formula will also work. First off, harmonicity makes the last term vanish. Then you want to use the martingale property to make the expectation of the middle term vanish. Then you get $E[u(B_{t \wedge \tau})]=u(B_0)$. Note that this requires $t \wedge \tau$ to satisfy the hypotheses of the optional stopping theorem, so you'll need to check that (and to be sure that you have the stopping time you need, which should indeed be the time to hit $\partial B_r$).

Comment: I guess you mean $E(u(B_0))$ on LHS.  I still don't see why RHS is the integral I need but I will think about it. thank you

Comment: $B_0$ is constant, so $E[u(B_0)]=u(B_0)$. Anyway, a clearer sketch: let $\tau$ be the time to hit $\partial B_r$, then $E[u(B_{t \wedge \tau})]=u(B_0)$ by some martingale arguments. Now send $t \to \infty$. The right side is fixed, and $B_{t \wedge \tau} \to B_\tau$ a.s. as $t \to \infty$. (That follows readily provided $\tau<\infty$ a.s.) Now try to interchange limit and expectation.

Comment: In case that you are interested in a reference: A proof can be found in *René Schilling, Lothar Partzsch: Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*.